# After Clean and Build in netbeans IDE 7.3 program dosn't work

Tags: java, process, netbeans-7, runtime.exec

After Clean and Build in netbeans IDE 7.3 program dosn't work:
this is a snapshot of my code :

```
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
          try {
              String programPath = "\"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" ";
              String parameter = "\"G:\\Quran\\Fares Abbad\\006.mp3\"" ;
              p = run.exec(programPath + parameter);
          } catch (IOException ex) {

          }
```

but after I get .jar file on dist Folder the program doesn't run and execute the command

```
p = run.exec(programPath + parameter);
```

but when I'm running my application from netbeans It work 100% where is the error??

Thank's in advance

Comment: 1) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: it is a Form >>> from netbeans just hit run button >>> after get jar file double click

Comment: Andrew Thompson >>> e.printStackTrace(); >> nothing happen and ProccessBuilder same thing work in netbeans but out of it it doesn't work

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for you and for your article the problem solved by removing \" from the programPath and parameter and put it in array this is the code
 Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
              try {
                  
                  String programPath = "C:\\Program   Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
                  String parameter = "G:\\Quran\\Fares Abbad\\006.mp3" ;
                  String[] all = {programPath,parameter};
                  p = run.exec(all);
               
:::
Thanks for your tips

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :) You should now either enter that as an answer and accept it, or delete the question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson this message appear 
Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

so you can put it as answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.

If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.

Then ignore that the article refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: remove \" from porgramPath, parameter variables and put them in an array then passing it to Runtime.exec() 

this is the final code

    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
              try {
                  
                  String programPath = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
                  String parameter = "G:\\Quran\\Fares Abbad\\006.mp3" ;
                  String[] all = {programPath,parameter};
                  p = run.exec(all);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }